# Verifiying contents of page source (nightwatch.js)

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm having trouble verifying that a certain string exists in a page's source in nightwatch.js

Basically, I'm trying to replicate the verifyHtmlSource command from Selenium IDE.

Does anyone know how to verify that a certain string exists in a page's source in Nightwatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test for a string within a page's source with the following code:

.source(function (result){ 
_browser.verify.equal((result.value.indexOf('STRING IN PAGE SOURCE TO MATCH AGAINST') > -1), true)
})

Answer (score 1):

On way would be to call `.containsText` on the body:

```
.assert.containsText('body', 'my text')
```

Comment: I need to check for something that is loaded via javascript and it doesn't appear anywhere on the page, only in the source. I know that the page's source is printed in the following example but is there a command that can be run against the result.value variabe to verify that particular string exists in it?                                                                                         `browser
    .url("http://www.google.com")
    .source(function (result){
        // Source will be stored in result.value
        console.log(result.value);
    })`

Comment: Your original post doesn't contain enough information to provide a better answer. So please update with a reproducible example.